# What are some DVD Unprotecting software?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, ripping, copy-protection

Can you please list off what are some DVD unprotecting applications that are available to download. I use [Need4Video DVD Ripper](http://need4video.com/dvd-ripper.html) to rip my DVDs. However, it will only rip unprotected DVDs.

I will **not** be doing anything that will be illegal. Only ask this question so that I can put my DVDs on a hard drive. So that I will not have to bring my DVDs to Afghanistan.

*Note: Must be compatible with Windows 7*

Comment: I changed my answer to AnyDVD until there better program suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try AnyDVD from Slysoft, http://www.slysoft.com/en/
They have a suit of products that allow you to unprotect and copy the DVD on your hard disk.

Comment: Thank you Dheer. I already bought it a while back but forgot about it. I will try it again.

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of handbrake. DVD to MP4 in one easy step.

Answer (score 0):

[DVD43](http://www.dvd43.com/) is a free decrypter. It can be used with Nero, Roxio annd many others, although for ripping DVDs (and other encoding tasks) I like [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

Comment: URL is a spam site now.