# Is there a way to have a DVD/CD virtual drive installed and store DVDs in an .iso file?

Tags: iso-image

I'm currently playing Crysis, but I also like to play Worms Armageddon sometimes and both of them need their respective DVDs to run.

I'd like to know if there's a way to copy the files off the DVD, store them in my computer and load it with a virtual DVD drive like Daemon Tools Lite?

Comment: techie is right - SU not the place to ask how to crack games, but of his three related questions, two of them have accepted answers or highest-rated ones pointing to slysoft...

Comment: Which OS are you using? MacOs, Gnu+Linux, Microsoft NT based or other.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  They're generally referred to as "NO-CD Cracks" and they're illegal to use in many countries, as you are trying to circumvent copyright protection mechanisms (that you agreed to when you bought/opened/used the game).

Good news is, many countries DO allow them because it's the only way you can make your "one legitimate backup" media.

I suggest you determine your local laws pertaining to their use (and/or any program like them), and when you go looking for them on the Internet, ensure you send every one you want to try through VirusTotal.com (or alike) before running it. :)

Beyond that, this isn't the place to ask how to crack games.  Unless perhaps you've got a very specific, on-topic question about a cracking problem, which doesn't pertain to any specific title(s).

Here's some related SuperUser questions to check out for more info:

- [How does DVD anti-piracy work?](https://superuser.com/questions/337585/how-does-dvd-anti-piracy-work?rq=1)
- [What are some DVD Unprotecting software?](https://superuser.com/questions/214454/what-are-some-dvd-unprotecting-software?rq=1)
- [How to create an image of DVD which is protected?](https://superuser.com/questions/226270/how-to-create-an-image-of-dvd-which-is-protected)

Comment: For everybody who's saying I wanna crack a game, THAT'S NOT what I was asking. I bought the DVDs. I bought the DVD of the game Crysis AND Worms Armageddon. I just don't wanna have to change the DVDs in the DVD drive all the time. Again, I'M NOT ASKING HOW TO CRACK ANYTHING. I just want to know if the information I bought that's on the DVD can be stored on the computer without having the DVD on my DVD drive bay. Hope you all understand this time.

Comment: Assuming the media in question has copy protection that's preventing you from just making an image and running it, then owned or not, illegal or not, you are still asking to defeat the copy protection which _is_ "cracking" it.   BTW, you didn't 'buy the information on the DVD', you purchased a license to use it.  If there is no copy protection involved, then where are you getting stuck while making the images?

Answer (score 1):

Not a buying recommendation, but Slysoft's [Game Jackal](http://www.slysoft.com/en/gamejackal.html) might be what you are after. Personally have used their DVD/BluRay equivalent for years without a problem.

Comment: I use this; works great.  It's like turning your disc-based games into Steam/Origin games.

Answer (score 0):

this is a great app that is free and very simple to use. You can have multiple iso files mounted at once as well.
And it will burn folders to isos, copy disks to isos.

Lots of great stuff
http://arainia.com/software/gizmo/

Comment: How is this any different then what Daemon Tools offers?

Comment: @techie007 have never used Daemon Tools, but this works reliably and is another choice

Comment: But how does this solve the user's problem?  He's got an ISO mounter already (Daemon Tools). :)

Comment: @techie007 sorry, yes this will burn dvds as well to iso images. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Software like this (including Daemon Tools) is detected by the anti-piracy tools in most games.